# Tabela para Downloads em PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, tabela-html, download

Estou criando um sistema em *PHP* de download de produtos digitais, vou explicar resumidamente:

1. Usuário entra no site, logo na página inicial, vai ter alguns produtos para download.
2. Ele se cadastra e compra o produto.
3. O produto deve ser listado para ele na seção de *Meus Downloads* em seu perfil.

A minha dúvida é, como eu vou fazer para verificar os downloads que esse usuário tem disponíveis no meu banco de dados?

Mais especificamente:

Tenho a seguinte tabela chamada downloads:

```
ID | NOME | DESCRIÇÃO | VERSÃO
```

Eu estava pensando em criar uma uma coluna na tabela de usuários, onde listará todos os ids dos downloads que esse usuário possuí, mas isso é possível?
Se não, o que vocês fariam?

Comment: poe um campo a mais na tabela com o valor de permissao, ex: 1-usuario normal; 2-usuario vip, etc. Ai na hora de puxar do banco de dados, basta verificar a perm do usuario e do produto/arquivo

Comment: Mas dessa forma o usuário teria acesso à todos os produtos, o que preciso é uma permissão individual para cada produto.

Comment: salve os id's dos produtos e o id do usuario em uma outra tabela, usa a junção de tabelas no SQL, ai basta consultar por esta tabela e exibir, tipo, quando o usuario comprar tal produto, salvaria na tabela o id dele, e do produto

Comment: Ou seja, devo criar uma nova tabela "compras", nessa tabela devo salvar o ID do usuário e o ID do plugin e depois faço um foreach no painel "Meus Downloads" do usuário?

Comment: mas nao necessariamente precisa usar  o foreach, é só consultar no BD, e dps com um while(); tbm da pra fazer,

Answer (score 0):

> *"Eu estava pensando em criar uma uma coluna na tabela de usuários, onde listará todos os ids dos downloads que esse usuário possuí, mas
>   isso é possível? Se não, o que vocês fariam?"*

Não acho que dê certo, pois assim cada usuário terá apenas disponível um DOWNLOAD para ele, visto que a coluna ID_DOWNLOAD vai armazenar apenas um ID referente a coluna downloads por usuário. O jeito certo é você criar uma terceira tabela USUARIOS_DOWNLOADS com as colunas ID_USUARIO e ID_DOWNLOAD.

Assim, a lógica das tabelas será: tabela DOWNLOADS: cadastro dos produtos; tabela USUARIO: cadastro dos clientes que vão consumir seus produtos; e tabela USUARIO_DOWNLOADS: cadastrar quais downloads vão relacionar com quais usuários. Exemplo:

**[Legenda] Tabela : campos=valores**
usuários: ID=100; NOME=JOSÉ; // ID=150; NOME=DANILO; 
downloads: ID=501; NOME=CURSO DE C#; // ID=502; NOME=CURSO DE C++; // ID=503; NOME=CURSO DE JAVA; 
usuarios_downloads : ID_USUARIO=100; ID_DOWNLOAD=501; // ID_USUARIO=100; ID_DOWNLOAD=502; // ID_USUARIO=150; ID_DOWNLOAD=503;

Pelo exemplo acima, JOSÉ (id=100) tem link para os cursos de C# e C++ (id=501 e id=502), e DANILO (id=150) tem acesso ao link do curso de JAVA (id=503).